# Ionic2 Push Notification Page move

Tags: push-notification, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I made Ionic2 App with notification using this plugin `https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push`. When the users receive the notification, depending on its data, I would like them to move the page accordingly.

I am sending `route` to `additionalData` to distinguish which page to guide them. In addition to this, I want to guide the user to specific tab of the page.

Any suggestion or advice would be appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

**app.components.ts**

```
declare var TabIndex: any; 

.....

push.on('notification').subscribe((notification:any) => {
    if (notification.additionalData.route == 'order-list') {
        console.log('order-list is selected');
        //WHAT DO I DO? 
        //I want the user to move to TabsPage(parent view) and its second-tab(child view)
    } else if (notification.additionalData.route == 'personal') {
        console.log('personal is selected');
        //I want the user to move to TabsPage and its third-tab
    } 
});
```

**EDITED:**

**app.components.ts**

```
push.on('notification').subscribe((notification:any) => {
    if (notification.additionalData.AppRoute == 'order-list') {
        console.log('move to orderlist');
        // this.nav.push(TabsPage, {"index" : 1});
        TabIndex = 1;
    } else if (notification.additionalData.AppRoute == 'order-home') {
        console.log('move to home');
        // this.nav.push(TabsPage, {"index" : 0});
        TabIndex = 0;
    }
});
```

**tabs.ts**

```
constructor(private navParams: NavParams) {
    if (TabIndex) {
        this.index = TabIndex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have `navParams` in your `Tabs.ts` (as in where the tabs are mentioned and in `Tabs.html`, you set it using `<ion-tabs>`).

You can send index of tab as `navParam` to this `tabs.ts`. Then, use `<ion-tabs selectedIndex="2">` in this page.

**tabs.ts**:

```
export TabsPage{
  index = 1;
  constructor(private navParams: NavParams){
    // This if() is for other cases where you don't want to send navParams. Like normally setting this page and selectedTab to 1.
    if(this.navParams.data.index !== undefined){
      index = this.navParams.data.index;
    }
  }
}
```

**tabs.html** :

```
<ion-tabs selectedIndex={{index}}>
  <ion-tab>..</ion-tab>
  ...
</ion-tabs>
```

And **app.component.ts**:

```
push.on('notification').subscribe((notification:any) => {
  if (notification.additionalData.route == 'order-list') {
    console.log('order-list is selected');
    this.nav.push(TabsPage, {"index" : 2});
  } else if (notification.additionalData.route == 'personal') {
    console.log('personal is selected');
    this.nav.push(TabsPage, {"index" : 3});
  } 
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It works! However, one more thing is that when I move to that specific page, tab area is hidden. How do I make tabs not hidden? 

I have tried '`tabsHideOnSubPages="false"` on `tabs.html`. However, it applied to every subpage, so could not use it.

Is there any way to pass `index` data to tabs.ts without `this.nav.push`?

Comment: I have edited question. Basically, I want to use global variable `TabIndex` so I can use it in `tabs.ts`, however, When I use TabIndex on `tabs.ts`, how can I use it?

Comment: Hey, I think you got this wrong.1. TabIndex is not a global variable to access in both. It is local to both classes. So, the TabIndex you refer in both is different. May be try using `localStorage`. 2. If you do not use `this.nav.push()` or `this.nav.setRoot()`, how would you go to Tabs page in first place?

Comment: Yes, I tried with `TabIndex` but it did not work .So I came back to `this.nav.push` and `this.nav.setRoot`. However, I cannot find a way to keep tab areas when using `this.nav.push`

Comment: My rootPage would be `TabsPage`, so I only need to select tab instead of  `this.nav.push`

Comment: Ohh, so you mean you will do something like `this.rootpage = TabsPage;`. Ok then, use localStorage. Or even `this.nav.setRoot();` could work if push is an issue.

Comment: I have used `this.nav.setRoot(TabPage, {"index" : 1})` then it moves to right page, but it still does not have tab area.